# Check which product the user bought on an In-App Purchase

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, in-app-purchase

I have used [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/21081/introduction-to-in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial) tutorial and wonder how to check **which** of the products the user just bought. I saw in the end of the tutorial:

> The resources zip for this tutorial contain images for all of the the
>   comics, so if you’re so inclined you can wrap it up by showing the
>   comic in a new view controller when a purchased row is tapped! **If you
>   want to do this, you can just check if the productIdentifier is in the
>   purchasedProducts array of the InAppRageIAPHelper before allowing the
>   user access to the content.**

But I tested but it wasn't a success. I
wonder if you know how to do it. Thanks for your time!

Comment: You could use the keychain as suggested here: https://fluffy.es/check-purchased-iap-using-keychain/

Answer (score 3):

One way could be to store purchased identifiers with NSUserDefaults.

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"YourIdentifier"];
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

You can then check when the app starts which identifiers has been bought

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"YourIdentifier"];
```

Comment: Note that storing data on `NSUserDefaults` is very insecure. Someone can easily overwrite its values to unlock IAP content.

Comment: I mean, as you can see on the tutorial, see which of them the user just bought.