# Following Ray Wenderlich's In App Purchase Tutorial, how do i implement logic to check if a product was purchased

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase, nsuserdefaults

his tutorial Introduction to In App Purchases http://www.raywenderlich.com/21081/introduction-to-in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial

how can I check if something is purchased? I want to check this with an if-statement. So, when "this" is bought, then do this and so on. I can't figure out what to write for the if-statement for the life of me.

can someone please answer this question explicitly? i have seen it posted in a few different places but none of the answers are straightforward enough for a complete novice like myself to comprehend. I found the exact same question here but the answer made no sense to me [Check which product the user bought on an In-App Purchase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18035040/check-which-product-the-user-bought-on-an-in-app-purchase)

specifically, what is the code to do this part
"The resources zip for this tutorial contain images for all of the the comics, so if you’re so inclined you can wrap it up by showing the comic in a new view controller when a purchased row is tapped! If you want to do this, you can just check if the productIdentifier is in the purchasedProducts array of the InAppRageIAPHelper before allowing the user access to the content."

I have everything working perfect from the tutorial, i just dont know how to use it.

i have a main menu view controller that has  3 buttons. i want to disable 2 of the buttons by default, but if the user has purchased the respective products, then i want to enable the buttons. i know it has something to do with NSUSerDefaults but I am very dense and am not able to understand a lot of the implicit answers people give for this question. If someone could spell it out for me I would be very grateful.

Thank you

Comment: There was a typo in the [answer you referenced](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18035193/475052) which I fixed. Does it make sense to you now?

Comment: Also this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16145640

Comment: carl, thanks a lot for the direction. i'm going to try and absorb the info from the links you provided and see if i can get it to work. ill keep you posted

Comment: carl! thanks so much man, this definitely got me on the right track. now i have the if statement set up correctly but my menu screen doesnt update to enabling the button immediately after purchasing it, instead i have to buy it, and then restart the app, and then it becomes enabled on the menu screen. i'm sure it's a simple fix somewhere, i'm gonna get to the bottom of it after some rest. thanks again man and is there anyway i can upvote you or something for providing the right answer?

Comment: Don't worry about it but thanks :). Re: your issue, post a notification / inform a delegate / or something like that when the purchase is successful... many examples to be found.

Comment: i ended up removing the logic from my viewDidLoad method to the viewWillAppear method and it works like a charm. thanks again for all the help